# Finding holomorphic map.

Tags: complex-analysis

How can one find a biholomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}\backslash [-i,i]$ (i.e. the plane with a segment removed) and $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$? (A biholomorphic map is a holomorphic one-to-one and onto function with holomorphic inverse function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Heuristic:* $\hat {\Bbb C}\backslash [-i,i]$ is simply-connected and its complement contains more than one point, therefore it can be mapped conformally to the unit disk $\Bbb D$, according to the Riemann mapping theorem. On the other hand, $\hat {\Bbb C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is *not* conformally equivalent to the unit disk. This suggests that the desired biholomorphism does not exist.

In this particular case one can also easily find a conformal map from $\Bbb C\backslash [-i,i]$ to $\Bbb D \setminus \{ 0 \}$ explicitly. (*Hint:* Start with a Möbiustransformation which maps $i, -i$ to $0, \infty$, respectively.)

Now show that there is *no* conformal mapping from $\Bbb D \setminus \{ 0 \}$ to $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. (*Hint:* Consider the inverse mapping. What kind of singularity would that function have at the origin?)

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform

Comment: Can you put in a few more details? Define $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, state the Riemann mapping theorem, explain which condition fails for $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @quarague: My problem: The question author asked for hints only and *not* a full answer, and you want full details, so what should I do now? –   $\hat {\Bbb C} = \Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$ is the extended complex plane.